# Javascript triangle determine

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a basic programme in javascript which determines what kind of Triangle is being made if someone inputs a certain variable into either 3 inputs.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

/*  Key/Legend
Var
    inp1 = input1
    inp2 = input2
    inp3 = input3
    Triangle_Inputs = Form Name

    */

/* Notes

    In computing, a parser is one of the components in an interpreter or 
    compiler that checks for correct syntax and builds a data structure 
    (often some kind of parse tree, abstract syntax tree or other hierarchical structure) 
    implicit in the input tokens.


    Technique
    if (side1 is equal to side2 AND side 2 is equal to side3) {equalitateral}

    if (side1 is equal to side2 AND side 2 doesn't equal to side3) {isosceles}

    if (side1 doesn't equal to side2 AND side2 doesn't equal to side 3 AND side 3 doesn't equal side 1) {scalene}

    http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

    */


function checkinputs()
{
/* Var = parseInt(document.Name_Of_Element_Form.Field_Name(Input).value); */
/* Input Fields */
inp1 = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input1.value);
inp2 = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input2.value);
inp3 = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input3.value);
/* Side options */
sideA = (inp1 + inp2);
sideB = (inp1 + inp3);
sideC = (inp2 + inp3);
    if (sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC) {
    alert("Equalateral");
    }
    if (sideA == sideB && != sideC) {
    alert("Isosceles");
    }
    if (sideA != sideB == sideC) {
    alert("Isosceles");
    }
    if (sideA != sideB != sideC != sideA) {
    alert("Scalene!");
    }
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="Container">

<div id="Header"><h1></h1></div>

        <div id="Content_1">
                <div id="Explanation">
                This calculator will determine what
                triangle you have made depending on
                the integer values in the input fields.

                </div>
                <div id="Form">
                    <FORM NAME="Triangle_Inputs" METHOD="GET">
                    Enter the triangle values below: <br>
                    <p>
                    <h4>Side 1: </h4><BR>
                    <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input1" VALUE=""><P>
                    <h4>Side 2: </h4><BR>
                    <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input2" VALUE=""><P>
                    <h4>Side 3:</h4> <BR>
                    <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input3"  VALUE=""><P>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Submit" Value="Submit" Class="Submit" onClick="checkinputs()">
                    </FORM>
                </div>
                <div id="Verbal_Output">
                    <h2>You made a:</h2>
                    <p>        
                    <h2>Triangle</h2>
                </div>

            </div>
            <p>
            <p>
        <div id="Content_2">

        <div id="Image_Output">asdad</div>
    </div>      
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

However I think I'm missing something, I can't seem to get the alert to tell the user anything.

Thanks everyone, sorry for posting this question it's just really confusing me

Comment: You can't chain logical comparisons like that - that gets parsed like `(sideA == sideB) == sideC` , which compares a true/false with the third side and is very unlikely to be true. Try something like `sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your speedy response. I'm just trying that now.

Would that mean that for the Isosceles it would be

if (sideA == sideB && != sideC)

Answer (score 3):

Try with this function:

```
function getTriangleType(a,b,c) {
  return (a === b && b === c) && 'equilateral' ||
  (a === b || a === c || b === c) && 'isosceles' ||
  'scalene';
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/eyoxor/3/edit

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's opened an insight into how I will go about making my programme. However I am using other methods for now :) 

Still thank you very much

Comment: My point is you don't need to check for `scalene` if the other types are evaluated in this order...

Comment: Thank you for your respons elclanrs :) Once I actually get it working I will experiment with your method

Answer (score 0):

1. You are never calling `checkinputs` function, so the form is never converted into sideA,B,C.
2. You are missing a } in your `equation` function. Remember to properly indent your code to spot these errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, How would I go around using checkinputs? Is that in the function itself or would that be a seperate function.

Also I just edited the equation, thank you for spotting the missing }

Comment: So many ways to handle that. You can call it from equations(), or you can create a new function that calls both of them.

Comment: I just edited the code above.

So inside function equations() { Call it here }

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain your comparisons together with logical operators, for example:

```
sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC
```

instead of

```
sideA == sideB == sideC
```